# Flutter : Check AppLifecycle event Suspending

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter docs about [AppLifecycle Event](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-listen-to-android-activity-lifecycle-events), it's have 4 Event .

- inactive
- paused
- resumed
- suspending

In 4 event above, i can print AppLifecycle event **inactive, paused, resumed**, but i can't handle **suspending** event.
Because i want check if the user kill/destroy the App from task manager. if the user kill/destroy the app , i want show Security Code (like PinCode etc).
How can i handle **suspending** event ?

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AppLifecycleState _appLifecycleState;
  FunctionHelper functionHelper = FunctionHelper();
  PageController _pageController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState appLifecycleState) {
    setState(() {
      _appLifecycleState = appLifecycleState;
    });
    print(appLifecycleState);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_appLifecycleState == null) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('This widget has not observed any lifecycle changes.'),
      );
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: Text(
            'The most recent lifecycle state this widget observed was: $_appLifecycleState'),
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter does not have any API to use `onDestroy` method of Activity [flutter/flutter#21982](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21982). During the suspending event the application is suspended momentarily which is equivalent to `onStop` in Android. When user kills or destroys the App, the `onDestroy` is triggered in Android therefore it cannot be handled using suspending event.

Comment: interisting, so it's possible to check duration of `paused` event ? 
If i can't handle `suspending` event, i want check duration of `paused` event , if `paused` event > ? second/minute then ...
it's possible?

Comment: You can start a Timer when `paused` event is called and check the condition or start a count down timer

Comment: But, if i have 3 screen, so i should check `paused` event in all screen or i can only check in 1 screen ?

Comment: How can i check if event in background or closed